# what does Dead Code mean under Eclipse IDE Problems Section

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Helios IDE for our Web Application development.
Under Problems section in Eclipse, for some of lines the description is displayed as "Dead Code".

Could anybody please tell me what does Dead Code actually mean ?

Please see the screen shot for your reference.

[image]

For example this part is shown as dead code under Eclipse

```
 else {
        int length;
        if (ar != null)
            length = Array.getLength(ar);
        else
            length = 0; // This line is dead code
```

Comment: Presumably because it can prove that `ar` will NEVER be null there - without more code we can't say for sure (but otherwise it'd be a bug and I'm more inclined to search for bugs in your code than in the eclipse compiler ;) )

Comment: Just worth noting - Eclipse sometimes gets this wrong.  I have seen Eclipse Neon give the "dead code" error for code that is provably not dead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Eclipse, "dead code" is code that will never be executed. Usually it's in a conditional branch that logically will never be entered.

A trivial example would be the following:

```
boolean x = true;
if (x) {
   // do something
} else {
   // this is dead code!
}
```

It's not an error, because it's still valid java, but it's a useful warning, especially if the logical conditions are complex, and where it may not be intuitively obvious that the code will *never* be executed.

In your specific example, Eclipse has calculated that `ar` will always be non-null, and so the `else length = 0` branch will never be executed.

**And yes, it's *possible* that Eclipse is wrong, but it's much more likely that it's not.**

Comment: I have modified my question , my question is  please tell me how can Eclipse decide that this is dead code ?? because in my opinion Eclipse suggestion might be also wrong know ??

Comment: @skaffman, Is dead code removed so that it doesn't appear in the bytecode?

Answer (score 5):

Dead code is code that will never be executed, e.g.

```
 boolean b = true
 if (!b) {
    .... 
    // dead code here
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Dead code means, that there is no way that this code will be executed.

Sometimes you even can't compile it (like this case:)

```
private Boolean dead_code()
    {
    return true;
    //Dead code below:
    dosomething();
    }
```

But in other cases this is not too obvious,  eg this statement:

```
   b=true;
   [...]
   if (b==false)
    {
    //Dead code
    }
```

If you have this message, there **is** some major flaw in your code. You have to find it, otherwise your app won't work as intended.

Comment: I like your first example, but disagree with "there **is** some major flaw". This is not necessarily so, for example I often use a static boolean "debug" parameter that will execute some code only if the parameter is set to true. For releases I change the parameter to false and as a result I get a lot of dead code warnings because the "debug" code parts will never be executed.

Comment: You are right, I did not think of this case. That would indeed result of a lot of dead code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two kinds of diagnostics that Eclipse gives out for marking code that will/may not be executed at runtime. 
1) Unreachable code: These are the usual java warnings that follow the unreachability rules of the JLS, and are also given by javac. These are meant to be compile errors. Examples:

```
   int foo() {
      return 1;
      int i = 1; // Unreachable
   }
   int foo2() {
     while (true);
     int i =1; //Unreachable
   }
```

There are other more complicated examples :)

2) Dead code: This is Eclipse's own static analysis warnings, and are mostly tied out of the null analysis i.e.

```
   void foo() {
     Object o = null;
     if (o == null) {
     } else {
     // dead code
     }
```

The examples given above should NOT give a dead code warning. i.e.

```
boolean x = true;
if (x) {
   // do something
} else {
   // this is dead code!
}
```

should not give the warning, because JLS forbids the compiler to evaluate the 'value' of variables. All that we can evaluate is the 'nullness'

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You might be having an Null pointer exception in the lines above the "Dead Code" lines.
Make sure you check for "Null Pointer" exception.

Comment: I would also say: You might be having a compiler obvious Null pointer exception :), i.e. a condition if your code that surely will lead to Null pointer exception on the line that gave that warning so that even the compiler understands this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have  used the variable `ar` before. Then the compiler knows that the line in the else statement will never be executed. Either there will be a `NullPointerException` at the place where you used `ar` or the first part of the `if` statement will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

let me give some answer for the dead code.

**Eg:**

```
public class UnreachableTest{

    public static void main(){

        try{
            // some code
        }
        catch(Exception exc){
            throw new NullPointerException();
            System.out.println("Unreachable line"); // compile time error
        }
    }

}
```

here the System.out.println("Unreachable line"); is never executed.
Which in turn considered to be a dead code.

Another example may be:

```
int func(int i, int j)
{
int sum = i + j;
return i + j; // never actually using the sum 
}
```

simple the function returns i + j; never really uses sum.
Sum is considered to be dead code here.

Answer (score 0):

Some other case when this happens.

```
System.out.println("result :" + result + ":" + result.isEmpty());
if (result == null)
    return result;
else if(!result.isEmpty())
    str.append(result + " ");
```

1) Here as you you are printing result and checking isEmpty() eclipse assumes that result is not null so it will not go in if. So return result is dead code.

2)Now let say result is coming null so you will get NullPointerException in result.isEmpty() so again it will not go in if and return result is deadcode

To make this work just comment out System.out.println().

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse gives this warning if the condition check you are giving may never be satisfied. Following are some examples

```
Object o=null;
if(o!=null) {
 //Some code

}
```

Here Dead code warning will come as Object is already made null

Another example is given below

```
BSTTest bstTest=null;
bstTest.test=10;
if(bstTest==null) {
  //some code

}
```

Here the code is trying to access a variable of the class. As the variable is already accessed, eclipse will give dead code warning in if(bstTest==null) as bstTest may not be null when the variable is already accessed.

Note: Here bstTest.test will give null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Example of Dead Code**

```
public class IfTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (true) {
            if(false) {
                System.out.println("a"); //Dead code, Never be Execute this if block.
            }else {
                System.out.println("b");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the term's Unreachable code and dead code:

**Unreachable Code** is a code block/statement in Java to which the control never reaches and never gets executed during the lifetime of the program. Following is the example of unreachable code. This generates compiler time error.

```
public void unreachableCodeExample() {
     System.out.println("This will execute");
     return;
     System.out.println("This will not"); //This is Unreachable code
 }
```

**While A Dead code** is an unreachable code, but it doesn’t generate compile time error. But if you execute it in eclipse (Or some other IDE) it gives you a warning. See below example,

```
public void deadCodeExample() {
        if (true) {
            System.out.println("This will execute");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("This will not"); //This is dead code
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dead code is the section of our code that is never going to execute runtime, its useless
EX:

```
if(false){ // statements }
```

For more example u can refer : [DeadCode Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/dead-code-examples)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
while (true) {
    if(false == true) break;

}

S.O.P("I will never reach here!") <-- This code will never be executed.
```

The code is valid as it conform to the compiler, however in reality the loop will never exit, and in effect S.O.P will never be executed.