# Why is Eclipse telling me that I have a "Dead code"?

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop

I cannot figure out why Ecplise won't let me execute the 3rd statement (i++) in my for loop due to it being "Dead Code", which I don't even know what that means. Anyone know why?

```
 public int getIdx(int studID) {
        for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
            if (this.StudID[i] == studID) {
                return i;
            }
            break;
        }
        return -1;      
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect `break;` to do? And when does it occur?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what does Dead Code mean under Eclipse IDE Problems Section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713557/what-does-dead-code-mean-under-eclipse-ide-problems-section)

Comment: What's the value of `classSize`? Is it fixed?

Comment: @nitind `classSize` is a user input. My code's purpose is to basically tell me the position of each student according to their student ID, and the nb of students must be smaller than `classSize`

Answer (score 3):

This is because your loop breaks after first iteration.

```java
public int getIdx(int studID) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
    if (this.StudID[i] == studID) {
      return i;
    }
    break; // <-- because of this, second iteration is never executed
  }
  return -1;      
}
```

Did you mean to place `break` under the `if` condition? If so, actually, you don't need it since `return` already breaks a loop.

It seems like you're trying to do lineary search. Here is how it may look like.

```java
public int getIdx(int studID) {
  for (int i = 0; i < classSize; i++) {
    if (this.StudID[i] == studID) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;      
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to fix the dead code problem. However, is it normal that my code always returns -1 no matter what?

Comment: You should check your `StudID` and `classSize` values. You may forgotten to initialize `classSize` and it may be 0, so no iteration is performed

Answer (score 1):

The dead code pretty much means that there will be lines of code that are never going to run. Such as having always true in an if-else statement. Your loop will break after the first iteration, so it is pointless to have a for-loop if the line of code is gonna execute only once.

Removing the `break;` should do the trick! You don't need to stop the loop because it already does when you return the `i` variable.